# Range of plot function does not accept Dynamic output

Tags: plotting, dynamic, slider

Below is some code to produce a Fourier series. I want to be able to adjust `L` to change not only the function, but also the plot limits.

I am getting the error :

> *"Limiting value -0.536 in {x, -0.536, 0.536} is not a machine-sized real number."*

```
Slider[Dynamic[L]]
Plot[Dynamic[L]/2 + 
  Sum[(2*Dynamic[L]/(n*Pi)^2)*((-1)^n - 1)*(Cos[
      n*Pi*x/Dynamic[L]]), {n, 3}], {x, Minus[Dynamic[L]], 
  Dynamic[L]}]
```

I am inexperienced with *Mathematica*, any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica!   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m = 1; Slider[Dynamic[m]]
Dynamic[
 Plot[
  m/2 + Sum[
          (2*m/(n*Pi)^2)*((-1)^n - 1)*(Cos[n*Pi*x/m])
        , {n, 3}]
  , {x, -m, m}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

EDIT

Follow @Amir's  comments and read the documentation for [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)

[image]

Comment: Beware of using uppercase variables, as they can collide with built in functions in Mma.

Comment: Thank you, this works as I had wanted. What exactly is the implication of wrapping all of Plot in Dynamic[]? When does it update exactly? Thank you again for your quick answer

Comment: @Amir see the docs on `Dynamic[ ]` under `Examples\Scope\Placing Dynamic`

Comment: @Amir in short, the problem is, that `Dynamic[x]` is **not** internally considered a number, even if `x` is a number. It is closer to a "display form". Wrapping `Plot` in `Dynamic` let's the entire plot be dynamically updated, while `Plot` itself needs numerical arguments, which `Dynamic` things are not. It's like doing `a = ... //MatrixForm; b = ...//MatrixForm; a.b (* Error *)` Instead one does `(a = ...)//MatrixForm`. But `Dynamic` is much much more than a comment can contain, so please do read up on it.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to use `Manipulate`. It is designed to handle the problem you have presented and takes care of all that `Dynamic` stuff internally.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[m/2 +
   Sum[
    (2*m/(n*Pi)^2)*((-1)^n - 1)*(Cos[n*Pi*x/m]), {n, 3}
    ],
  {x, -m, m}
  ],
 {{m, 1}, 0.1, 5.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]